# Ubuntu 12.10 auto-hide dock fragments

Tags: ubuntu, hide, nvidia, dock

I just installed a new graphics card (NVIDIA GTX 650) to my Ubuntu 12.10 computer. Since installing the card, the Ubuntu dock leaves a grey bar whenever the dock autohides.

Has anyone of you experienced that kind of behaviour?

Thanks in advance,
Matthias

Comment: This is [off-topic for Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions). You might want to ask about this on [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com) (but search for it there first!).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For all looking for the same answer as me, there is a nice blog post on how to get NVIDIA drivers running in Ubuntu. Using the proprietary driver everything works ok. Here's the link:
http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/ubuntu-quetzal-nvidia.html